# element-by-element multiplication within a data table - Multiple variables at the same time (R)

Tags: r, data.table

Let's say I have the following data table in `R`:

```
L3 <- LETTERS[1:3]
(d <- data.table(cbind(x = 1, y = 1:10), fac = sample(L3, 10, replace = TRUE)))
vecfx=c(5.3,2.8)
```

and I would like to compute two new variables, `dot1` and `dot2` that are:

```
d[,dot1:=5.3*x]
d[,dot2:=2.8*y]
```

But I don't want to compute them this way as this is a relaxation of my problem. In my original problem, `vecfx` consists of 12 elements and my data table has twuelve columns so I want to avoid writing that twuelve times.

I tried this: `vecfx*d[,list(x,y)]` but I'm not getting the desired result (it seems like the product is done by rows instead of by columns). Also, I want to create those  two new variables within my data table `d`.

This is also useful when one wants to create several columns at the same time within a data table in `R`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update: In [v1.8.11](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=240), [FR #2077](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?func=detail&atid=978&aid=2077&group_id=240) is now implemented - `set()` can now add columns by reference, . From [NEWS](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?view=markup&root=datatable):**

> `set()` is able to add new columns by reference now. For example, `set(DT, i=3:5, j="bla", 5L)` is equivalent to `DT[3:5, bla := 5L]`. This was `FR #2077`. Tests added.

with which one would then be able to do (as @MatthewDowle suggests under comments):

```
for (j in seq_along(vecfx)) 
    set(d, i=NULL, j=paste0("dot", j), vecfx[j]*d[[j]])
```

---

I think you're looking for `?set`. Note that `set()` also adds by reference and is very fast! Pasting the relevant section from `?set`:

> Since `[.data.table` incurs overhead to check the existence and type of arguments (for example), `set()` provides direct (but less flexible) assignment by reference with low overhead, appropriate for use inside a for loop. See examples. `:=` is more flexible than `set()` because `:=` is intended to be combined with `i` and by in single queries on large datasets.

```
for (j in seq_along(vecfx)) 
    set(d, i=NULL, j=j, vecfx[j]*d[[j]])
      x    y fac
 1: 5.3  2.8   B
 2: 5.3  5.6   C
 3: 5.3  8.4   C
 4: 5.3 11.2   C
 5: 5.3 14.0   B
 6: 5.3 16.8   B
 7: 5.3 19.6   C
 8: 5.3 22.4   C
 9: 5.3 25.2   C
10: 5.3 28.0   C
```

It's just a matter of providing the right indices to `set`.

Comment: Great @Arun, but what if one would like to add those two new columns to the data table. I mean, the data table has to have dot1 and dot2 as two new variables. The computation is ok, but just want to add them, not replace the existing ones.

Comment: `j=paste0("dot",j)` in the `set` call should do it.

Comment: Oh yes, we should really fix that. It's FR#2077.

Comment: I put d[,paste0("dot",1:2):=0] and then Arun's solution...           for (j in seq_along(vecfx)) set(d, i=NULL, j=paste0("dot",j), vecfx[j]*d[[j]]) and that works. Thank you very much. Cracks :)

Answer (score 8):

Arun's answer is good.

The LHS and RHS of `:=` accept multiple items so another way is :

```
d[,paste0("dot",1:2):=mapply("*",vecfx,list(x,y),SIMPLIFY=FALSE)]
d
    x  y fac dot1 dot2
 1: 1  1   C  5.3  2.8
 2: 1  2   B  5.3  5.6
 3: 1  3   C  5.3  8.4
 4: 1  4   C  5.3 11.2
 5: 1  5   B  5.3 14.0
 6: 1  6   A  5.3 16.8
 7: 1  7   A  5.3 19.6
 8: 1  8   B  5.3 22.4
 9: 1  9   A  5.3 25.2
10: 1 10   A  5.3 28.0
```

Maybe there's a better way than that. I think Arun's `for` should be faster though, and maybe easier to read.